# Can't make weld scanning beans

Tags: tomcat, servlets, cdi, weld

I must have missed something but I can't make Weld working !
It's a simple webapp, one servlet, one service (that i'd like to inject in the servlet)

here are the files :

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

context.xml

```
<Context>
       <Resource name="BeanManager"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
          factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
    </Context>
```

my service

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ServiceTest {


    public String test(){
        return "hello world";
    }


}
```

my servlet :

```
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    private ServiceTest service;

    @Override
       public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                   throws IOException, ServletException {
          // Set the response message's MIME type.
          response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
          // Allocate a output writer to write the response message into the network socket.
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

             try {
             out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");  // HTML 5
             out.println("<html><head>");
             out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");
             String title = service.test();
             out.println("<title>" + title + "</title></head>");
             out.println("<body>");
             out.println("<h1>" + title + "</h1>");  // Prints "Hello, world!"
             out.println("</body></html>");
          } finally {
             out.close();  // Always close the output writer
          }
       }
}
```

I'm just getting a NPE ... nothing else.

here is the starting trace of my Tomcat 7

```
2016-06-07 22:49:27 DEBUG logging:37 - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
2016-06-07 22:49:27 INFO  servletWeldServlet:57 - WELD-ENV-001008: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
2016-06-07 22:49:27 INFO  Version:153 - WELD-000900: 2.3.4 (Final)
2016-06-07 22:49:27 DEBUG Bootstrap:121 - WELD-ENV-000030: Cannot load class using the ResourceLoader: org.jboss.jandex.Index
2016-06-07 22:49:27 DEBUG Bootstrap:121 - WELD-ENV-000030: Cannot load class using the ResourceLoader: org.jboss.jandex.Index
2016-06-07 22:49:27 DEBUG Bootstrap:316 - WELD-ENV-000024: Archive isolation enabled - creating multiple isolated bean archives if needed
2016-06-07 22:49:27 INFO  Bootstrap:166 - WELD-ENV-000028: Weld initialization skipped - no bean archive found
juin 07, 2016 10:49:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
juin 07, 2016 10:49:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
juin 07, 2016 10:49:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 1127 ms
```

beans.xml (under META-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
    <scan>

    </scan>
</beans>
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace with NPE.

Comment: Do you have beans.xml somewhere?

Comment: the NPE give no information, just a call on the injected object which is null.

Comment: I've added the beans.xml which is in the META-INF

Comment: [Where](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/) did you read that you should place `beans.xml` in `/META-INF` of an WAR archive?

Comment: My mistake, should be in WEB-INF, I'll check this out and see it it solves my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2016-06-07 22:49:27 INFO  Bootstrap:166 - WELD-ENV-000028: Weld initialization skipped - no bean archive found

This means Weld did not find any bean archive in your WAR. Note that in a WAR, `beans.xml` must be named `WEB-INF/beans.xml` or `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml` (see also the spec [12.1. Bean archives](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive)). I guess that you have `META-INF/beans.xml`.